# Azure - Can not deploy windows function app if using managed identity for storage

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions, identity

I've successfully set up a user assigned identity on my function app to allow access to the function storage account. The app configuration parameter `AzureWebJobsStorage` has changed to `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName` and my resources are accessible. I then decided to make a change to my code and attempted to deploy it which resulted in the following error:

`app is missing AzureWebJobsStorage app setting. That setting is required for publishing consumption linux apps.`

Which is funny because I'm not using Linux. Apparently this is due to a [hard coded check](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/d1676f65bc643396ea1f562ac29cf2c66cd55d05/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py#L539-L545) in the Azure SDK itself looking for that exact config value. It doesn't seem to check if we are using Linux or Windows before erroring out, and it doesn't check if we are using a managed identity/have the `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName` key set.

I've seen these two issues on github related to the problem
[first](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2222)
[second](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2671)

the one still open doesn't seem to be getting any attention. I see as a viable option to use a URL instead of setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` but [according to azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#considerations-for-deploying-from-a-url) there's some non-trivial downsides to not running from a package.

My question is - is it possible to keep `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` and use managed identity for storage in a function app? I saw there is a powershell script for hacking around this issue, but I would like to avoid that if possible.